# Отловить ошибку в concat RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava2

Например, есть локальный репозиторий и сетевой

```
Observable.concat(
                localDao.getAll().firstElement().toObservable(),
                api.get()
                        .filter(Checker::checkResponse)//выбрасываем ошибку если что то не так с данными
                        .flatMapObservable(data-> Observable.just(data.getData()))
                        .flatMap(data-> localDao.insert(data).flatMapObservable(d -> Observable.just(data))))                  
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Как сделать чтобы ошибка из репозитория пошла вверх только в случае если нету данных в обоих репозиториях?

Например, может быть так, что, нету сети, и сетевой репозиторий выбросит ошибку, но в этот момент у нас есть локальные данные и мы показываем их - нам не нужно отлавливать ошибку.

Например, может быть так, что, нету сети, и сетевой репозиторий выбросит ошибку, и в этот момент у нас нету локальных данных - нам нужно отлавливать ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

как то так

```
return api.get()
    .filter(Checker::checkResponse) //выбрасываем ошибку если что то не так с данными
    .flatMapObservable(data-> Observable.just(data.getData()))
    .flatMap(data-> localDao.insert(data).flatMapObservable(d -> Observable.just(data)))
    .onErrorResumeNext(localDao
                           .getAll()
                           .firstElement()
                           .doOnNext( // обновить локальную БД) 
    );
```